# jQuery: wrap <span> around substring...close, but not quite

Tags: javascript, jquery, substring

I'm attempting to select substrings--the character count, in square brackets--within several paragraphs and wrap each of them in `<span>` tags with a class, `char_count`, applied. Here's the HTML for one, and the CSS:

```js
var select_p = $('div#promo_area div.featured_box p');
select_p.each(function() {
  var first_index = $(this).html().indexOf('[');
  var last_index = $(this).html().indexOf(']') + 1;
  var selected_text = $(this).html().substring(first_index, last_index);
  selected_text.wrap('<span class="char_count" />');
});
```

```css
span.char_count {
  padding-top: 0;
  color: #ff6600 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="promo_area">
  <h3>Featured Stories</h3>
  <div class="featured_box">
    <h4><a href="/give">Senectus et Netus</a></h4>
    <div>
      <a href="/give"><img width="207" height="139" src="http://myrussreid.com/files/2011/06/ffffff1395-207x139.jpg" class="attachment-wds_home_image wp-post-image" alt="ffffff139" title="ffffff139" /></a>
    </div>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus. [100 characters w/spaces]</p>
    <a href="/give">Please Give</a>
  </div>
  <!-- end .featured_box -->
</div>
```

It seems to work right up until the `.wrap` line—I get the correct substring in `selected_text`. The wrap itself doesn't work. What stupid little thing am I doing wrong? Or is it a stupid BIG thing?

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/imbwaldo/n2jca)'s my fiddle**.

Comment: Strings don't have a wrap method. You are mixing jQuery methods with native javascript methods.

Comment: `$('<span />').addClass("char_count").text(selected_text).appendTo(whatever)`

Comment: Makes sense, Kevin. Thank you for pointing that out. So much to learn, so little time...

Comment: Oooh. I'll tinker with that one, SpYk3HH. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try implementing a solution using ranges and `surroundContents` if you're feeling adventurous, or you could use [this](http://bartaz.github.com/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html) plugin to make it as easy as:

```
$(this).highlight(selected_text, { element: 'span', className: 'char_count' });
```

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kpn7b/2/

Comment: Thanks, Asad. The character counts will vary, though, which is why I'm trying to select by the only characters that'll be consistent--the square brackets. I'll explore ranges and `surroundContents` and see how adventurous I feel. :)

Comment: @imbwaldo Why can't you just use the plugin? The implementation is ridiculously simple, as you can see from the fiddle I provided.

Comment: Oh, duh. I missed that fiddle, Asad. You're right--it's ridiculously simple! I see how you used my selection as an argument. Fantastic. Thanks very much.

Comment: @imbwaldo Just for future reference, you can remove it again using `$(this).unhighlight()`

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
var selected_text = $(this).html().substring(first_index, last_index);
```

With:

```
var selected_text = $('<span class="char_count">').text($(this).html().substring(first_index, last_index));
```

Your  `selected_text` is a string, mine is a jQuery span object.

If you want to, you could use a script **similar** to this:

```
select_p.html(function(i, old) {
    return  old.replace(/(\[.*\])/gi, '<span class="char_count">$1</span>');
});
```

Comment: @Asad. That's true, but it leads him in the right direction, as right now he treats a string as it was a jQuery object....

Comment: True enough. You might want to complete this answer though.

Comment: @Asad. Honestly I wouldn't do that, using regex and stuff like that to manipulate HTML is not a wise thing to do.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Do I understand this correctly: I've turned my selection into a string and need to turn it into a jQuery object in order to wrap it? Or, gdoron, have you, in a single step, captured the string and turned it into an object? If so, how would I go about inserting it back into its space in the paragraph?

Comment: @imbwaldo. Look at the second `<p>` I added.

Comment: @imbwaldo As gdoron has already mentioned, using regexen on HTML is a poor idea.

Comment: Thank you both. I'm too new at this and find regex a bit intimidating. But I'll keep this in mind for future study....